# kernel messages "lost 9599 rtc interrupts"

Tags: linux, kernel

I just started getting these messages on my Fedora 23 x86_64 system. Can someone tell me what they mean please? rtc broken or failing?

```
Jun  4 01:32:54 fc23 kernel: hpet1: lost 9599 rtc interrupts
Jun  4 01:32:54 fc23 kernel: hpet1: lost 9600 rtc interrupts
Jun  4 01:32:55 fc23 kernel: hpet_rtc_timer_reinit: 1 callbacks suppressed
Jun  4 01:32:55 fc23 kernel: hpet1: lost 9600 rtc interrupts
Jun  4 01:32:56 fc23 kernel: hpet1: lost 9599 rtc interrupts
Jun  4 01:32:56 fc23 kernel: hpet1: lost 9599 rtc interrupts
```

Answer (score 2):

I observed the exact same messages with the exact same ridiculously high values of lost interrupts being logged all the time.

For me it was caused by kernel parameter "irqpoll" in combination with "pci=routeirq" on my system while using PCI soundcard on a MB with buggy PCIe-to-PCI bridge.

I run kernel 4.6.2 from Debian testing on MB Asus P8Z68-V PRO GEN3, BIOS 3802, UEFI boot.

My board has the buggy PCIe-to-PCI bridge (AsMedia 1083 rev.01) and I regularly observed Linux completely freezing during listening to music or watching fullscreen video.

The crashes occured since day one after installation, with onboard Intel soundcard (Intel HDA).
They occured also with additional SB PCI 128 plugged into one of the PCI slots. With the SB PCI card I observed all kind of log messages like "Disabling IRQ" or "hpet1 lost interrupts" (based on actual kernel parameters combination).

I tried to do all kind of tricks with kernel parameters to get the SB PCI 128 to work but the kernel hanged everytime so I had to force hard restart (not even SysRq worked).

Currently testing while booted with "irqpoll" only, using only the onboard Intel soundcard, so far no crash. There are a few messages about "hpet1" errors in kern.log, but they are generated in significantly lower frequency then when I used the SB PCI.

I suspect the buggy bridge is still in use by some other device (that's why these hpet1 errors are showing up I guess).

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Unix. +1. Any links about the problem?